# Noun for "things that could be improved"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a noun meaning "something that could be done to improve *x*"? If i was inventing one, i might call it "an improvable", but [improvable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/improvable) is an existing adjective.

Example: "I can give you some ___ for your project", or "There are a bunch of ___ you should do".

Comment: See if "material" (n.)  fits. Meaning-things needed for doing or making something. e.g. “writing materials”

Comment: @MystiSinha No, that's not it.

Comment: Your example would be "suggestions".  However, that's probably not what your looking for.  You might try to find a different example.

Comment: You're looking for "*an **improvement***". As in "*There are a lot of **improvements** you could make*" or "*I could suggest some **improvements***".

Comment: @DanBron That's an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how I missed the word "improvement".

> a change or addition by which a thing is improved. ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/improvement?s=t))

This was originally mentioned in a comment by [Dan Bron](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/55623/dan-bron).

Answer (score 2):

An imperfection. But really, everything can be improved (except perhaps God) so the question is really moot.

Comment: Which god are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing that comes to my mind is "deficiencies".

To use your examples, reworded:

> I've found some deficiencies in your project.

and

> There are a bunch of deficiencies you should correct.

This doesn't exactly mean things that can be improved, more like things that are lacking. But the implication is that the things that are lacking should be added / added to / corrected, which seems quite close.

Answer (score 0):

[Advancement](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Advancement) can be used to give the idea that the project can be improved:

> - A forward step; an improvement.

or [amelioration](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/amelioration):

> - The state of being ameliorated; improvement.

(from TFD)