# Noun for "Things that can be improved/might change their state"

Tags: single-word-requests

(Note that, while the title is similar, this is a very different question from [Noun for "things that could be improved"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221261/noun-for-things-that-could-be-improved/221285), as in that question, *things* refers to *properties on a single object*.)

I am looking for a (plural) noun to list `things that can still be improved` or `things that are not completed yet` or more general: `things that might still change their state`. I do not know how to make it more clear, other than to explain why I am looking for such a word:

I have a computer application that contains a list of tasks that undergo state changes, from *new*(when a task is made) to *in progress*(when work on it has started) to *completed*(when work has finished) to *closed*(when work has been checked, tested and accepted by the boss). There also is a *disregarded* state for tasks that are deemed unfixable or unimportant for some reason.

There is a page that lists all tasks in *new, in progress* and *completed*, as for all of these, there still is some action the user should take. Until now, this page is named *All*, but that name is confusing as *closed* and *disregarded* are not shown there. That is why I am looking for a better term to describe this page/tasks in this list.

Comment: Why not simply *open* or *unclosed*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since those tasks which have progressed through all still-changeable states are listed as "closed," wouldn't the appropriate designation for those which have not be "open?"

Comment: Indeed. One might say these are the tasks whose [*outcome is still **wide open.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22outcome+is+still+wide+open%22)

Comment: You are completely right. I think I was overcomplicating things.